# Perl replace delimiters

Tags: regex, perl, perl-module, perl-data-structures

I have CSV text like

```
1,2,3,{4,5,6,7,8},9,10,100
```

I want to replace the delimiter of fields between `{}`. The text should look like:

```
1,2,3,{4|5|6|7|8},9,10,100
```

I tried `perl -0777 -pe 's/\{.*?,\}/|/g'`

but nothing happens. What should I do instead?

Answer (score 2):

This will do as you ask. It replaces all commas that are followed by a sequence of characters that are *not* braces `{`  `}`, and then a closing brace

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $s = '1,2,3,{4,5,6,7,8},9,10,100';

$s =~ s/,(?=[^{}]*\})/|/g;

say $s;
```

**output**

```
1,2,3,{4|5|6|7|8},9,10,100
```

Comment: In case there is a stray closing curly bracket, this will also [trigger a replacement](https://regex101.com/r/uP8eA2/1) (e.g. `1,2,}3,{4,5,6,7,8},9,10,100`). Perhaps, that is not critical for OP, but my suggested solution only replaces the comma inside paired `{}`s.

Comment: If there is a *stray closing curly bracket* then the OP hasn't defined what behaviour they want, and it is pointless to speculate

Comment: Thanks Borodin, i should have mentioned this earlier, my text file has nested {}, like 1,2,3,a,b,c,d,{e,f,g,6,{8,9,4},{6,4,a,s,},2,3,4},4,d,f,g.  The above works for {8|9|4},{6|4|a|s|} but the e,f,g,6 part is unaffected. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @user4911736: That is a completely different problem. Please ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex with `$1$2|` replacement string:

```
(\{\s*|(?<!^)\G)(\d+),(?=[,0-9]*\})
```

Output:

```
1,2,3,{4|5|6|7|8},9,10,100
```

[Sample code](https://ideone.com/xauvlt):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$txt = "1,2,3,{4,5,6,7,8},9,10,100";
$txt =~ s/(\{\s*|(?<!^)\G)(\d+),(?=[,0-9]*\})/$1$2|/g;
print $txt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a command line version for Perl 5.14 and greater.

```
perl -pe 's/([{][\d,]+[}])/$1 =~ s~,~|~gr/ge'
```

The `/e` means it's evaluating the replacement as a Perl expression and not the standard regex expression. That means that it is taking the value of the first capture (`$1`) and performing a substitution *with return* (`/r`) so as to avoid the error trying to modify the read-only value (`$1`).

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
$st = "1,2,3,{4,5,6,7,8},9,10,100";
if ( $st=~/\{(.*)\}/ ) {
  $tr = $1;
  $tr =~ s/,/|/g;
  $st =~ s/\{*\}/{$tr}/;
  print "$st \n"
}
```

Output:

```
1,2,3,{4,5,6,7,8{4|5|6|7|8},9,10,100
```